# `does not write information to the database`

Tags: php, laravel, axios

`does not save to database`
help me understand my mistake

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $item = Cart::where('product_id', $request->product_id);

    if ($item->count()) {
        $item->increment('quantity');
        $item = $item->first();
    } else {
        $item = Cart::forceCreate([
            'product_id' => $request->product_id,
            'quantity' => 1,
        ]);
    }

    return response()->json([
        'quantity' => $item->quantity,
        'product' => $item->product
    ]);
}
```

**Store**

```
addProductToCart (product, quantity) {
        axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/cart', {
            product_id: product.id,
            quantity
        })
},
```

when clicking on the addItems(for instance) button, the items are not added to the database

Comment: Is this a frontend or backend issue?

Comment: can you please put scr shot off your javscript code for better understanding

Comment: @kissu it looks like it is front end issue

Comment: `looks like` is kinda slim as a lead. Do you send the proper info? Check your network traffic. Otherwise, check your database backend and try to add stuff to it manually.

Answer (score 0):

my mutation happened to be in the wrong module

```
  add_to_cart(state, {product, quantity}) {

        let productInCart = state.cart.find(item => {
            return item.product.id === product.id;
        });

        if (productInCart) {
            productInCart.quantity += quantity;
            return;
        }

        state.cart.push({
            product,
            quantity
        })
    },
```